# Getting WndProc without CreateWindowEx?

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, wndproc

I have started programming a small engine with some tutorials and a book, it works fine but now I want to build a editor with Qt. After I embedded the output into a `QtFrame` I realized I doesn't get any input because the `WndProc()` isn't called after `CreateWindowEx()`.

How can I fix that?

Comment: In Qt you should never ever have to deal with a WndProc directly for QtWidgets... Are you creating the frame from a different thread other than the GUI thread?

Comment: Does some other window have focus?

Comment: Only the main window with the frame.